# PHP can't read binary file?

Tags: php

I have a very simple PHP code which should read a binary file, but it doesn't work:

```
<?php
$fid = fopen("sampleMdl.bin","rb");
echo "No. parts: " . fread($fid, 2) . "<br/>";

fclose($fid);
?>
```

The first 2 bytes of sampleMdl.bin contain the integer 2. But the page displays nothing after "No. parts:".
Is there actually any setting in the server that avoids PHP to read binary file?

Comment: What is in the file?!

Comment: Numerical data. As I said, the first 2 bytes contains the integer 2.

Comment: Is it actually binary data? (The bytes `02 00` are in the file) If this is the case, then you need to interpret the bytes as integers. Otherwise PHP is going to assume strings. Or is it ASCII (The bytes `30 32` = "02" are in the file).

Comment: PHP reads binary data just fine. If you just dump that binary data out as is, it's up to the viewer/browser to interpret this binary gibberish. In this case you're apparently not outputting anything that shows up when interpreted as text. Try `bin2hex(fread($fid, 2))` for a change.

Comment: Thanks! I just realized about this (need to reinterpret the binary data as integer).

Comment: http://php.net/unpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution already by using a combination of unpack() and array_values():

```
<?php
$fid = fopen("sampleMdl.bin", "rb");
$NA = array_values(unpack("Sshort", fread(fid, 2)));
echo "No. parts: " . $NA[0] . "<br/>";

fclose($fid);
?>
```

Where the first 2 bytes of sampleMdl.bin is 02 00.

Answer (score 1):

You read a binary integer.

```
$bytes = fread($fld, 2);
$n = $bytes[0] | ($bytes[1] << 8); // The number
```

This is a little endian format; it could also be the other way around, big endian:

```
$n = $bytes[1] | ($bytes[0] << 8); // The number
```

In this case negative numbers do not happen, so this suffices.